# Why is ExtJS 5 Container click event no longer fired?

Tags: extjs

In our 4.2.2 app we registered a click event on a container as follows, but it does not work in ExtJS 5. Any ideas?

```
'afterrender': function(comp) {
    comp.getEl().on({
        'click' : {
            fn: function (el) {
                this.fireEvent('click', comp);
            },
            scope: comp
        },
        'mouseover' : {
            fn: function (el) {
                el.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
            },
            scope: comp
        }
    }, comp);
}
```

Comment: It's something with how the `on` method is using the `comp` scope that you're passing in... if you take off passing the scope in, it'll work.  I'd recommend refactoring this to have individual `on` calls, with references to handlers.

Comment: Removing the scope worked. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the scope "comp" from the end of the "on" call.

BEFORE:

```
'afterrender': function(comp) {
    comp.getEl().on({
        'click' : {
            fn: function (el) {
                this.fireEvent('click', comp);
            },
            scope: comp
        },
        'mouseover' : {
            fn: function (el) {
                el.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
            },
            scope: comp
        }
    }, comp);
}
```

AFTER:

```
'afterrender': function(comp) {
    comp.getEl().on({
        'click' : {
            fn: function (el) {
                this.fireEvent('click', comp);
            },
            scope: comp
        },
        'mouseover' : {
            fn: function (el) {
                el.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
            },
            scope: comp
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why was my post voted down? Upgrading to ExtJS 5 is a nightmare, and this seems like a valid question. I drove it to resolution with an answer. Now I can't ask questions in stack overflow, which I rely on because Sencha forums are often lame. Please help.